# How do I make a video file out of images in Java?

Tags: java

I specifically want to know how to make a video file using pictures JUST using Java. I understand if it isn't possible, but if anyone knows I would be extremely grateful.

As it currently stands I have a folder of 1000 videos I want to turn into a video with each image lasting 0.05 seconds each.

I am not particularly picky about the types of images needed to be used or the type of video file created, I would prefer if I can convert JPEGs to an MP4 file though.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for videos natively in Java. You need a third party library like [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/), which provides video encoding functionality.

With JCodec the following should work (not tested):

```
AWTSequenceEncoder encoder = AWTSequenceEncoder.createSequenceEncoder(new File("path/filename.mp4"), 25); // 25 fps
for (BufferedImage image : getImagesFromSomewhere()) {
    encoder.encodeImage(image);
}
encoder.finish();
```

Comment: I have an ArrayList of BufferedImages that I am using, but other than that I tried this same thing and it didn't work.

Comment: @George "it didn't work" isn't very helpful information to help you. I just tested the code and it works perfectly fine here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  does that help?

Comment: @George That's a very generic error, maybe create a new question with your code and the full error message. But try debugging it yourself first. Also if you decide to post a new question, don't forget to take this to heart: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323559/making-a-video-file-out-of-images-in-java

Answer (score -3):

The **ImageIO** library allows you to read/write a number of image formats, effectively allowing you to transcode images from, say, **.jpg -> BufferedImage -> .png**, or any which way you need to do it.

you can do something like,

```
public void createMovie(BufferedImage[] frames, String destinationFormat)
```

where "destinationFormat" is something like "m4v", "mpeg2", "h.264", "gif", etc.

How to use BufferedImage? You can refer [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_dip/java_buffered_image.htm)

Comment: i can see this was copied from another question which was similar. where does the Mp4 creation take place? using which library or class?

Comment: @John Can you specify how the array "frames" would be converted to an h.264? I have tried a couple of things like this `for(BufferedImage bi:frames)
            ImageIO.write(bi, "h.264", outputfile);` and I wasn't able to complete it.

Comment: This answer is wrong. ImageIO provides functionality for images, not videos.