# Making a video file out of images in Java?

Tags: java, jcodec

I make a robot that has an auto delay of 50 then do this.

```
for(int a=0;a<1000;a++;)
{
    Rectangle screenRect= new Rectangle(300,400);
    al.add(r.createScreenCapture(screenRect));
}
File outputfile = new File(output,"Test.mp4");
AWTSequenceEncoder enc = 
AWTSequenceEncoder.createSequenceEncoder(outputfile,20);
for (BufferedImage bi : al)
    enc.encodeImage(bi);
enc.finish();`
```

output is the path to my desktop. These are the errors I have gotten:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jcodec.containers.mp4.muxer.MP4Muxer.addTrack(MP4Muxer.java:91)
    at org.jcodec.containers.mp4.muxer.MP4Muxer.addTrack(MP4Muxer.java:87)
    at org.jcodec.containers.mp4.muxer.MP4Muxer.addVideoTrack(MP4Muxer.java:196)
    at org.jcodec.api.transcode.SinkImpl.outputVideoPacket(SinkImpl.java:69)
    at org.jcodec.api.transcode.SinkImpl.outputVideoFrame(SinkImpl.java:223)
    at org.jcodec.api.SequenceEncoder.encodeNativeFrame(SequenceEncoder.java:101)
    at org.jcodec.api.awt.AWTSequenceEncoder.encodeImage(AWTSequenceEncoder.java:49)
    at Test.main(Test.java:47)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
        symbol:   class Nullable
        location: package javax.annotation
             at org.jcodec.common.Preconditions.<clinit>(Preconditions.java:17)
             ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
        symbol:   class Nullable
        location: package javax.annotation
```

The compiler can't find *javax.annotation.Nullable*. You are using *Jcodec*, which depends on the *Javax.annotation API*, which you don't seem to have included. You can find it [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.1).

However, you should consider building your project with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), which will take care of such dependencies for you. I wouldn't be surprised if there are further dependencies hidden.